# Wordpress retain a selected value in a dropdown after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a complete novice but trying to design my first site in Wordpress. I am trying to retain the value of a dropdown that pulls values from a database after a form is submitted. I have searched many questions and tried many different ways of trying to write selected="selected" in my code but none of them seem to work. Please help.

Here is my code that just pulls from the database but isn't trying to retain the selected value:

```
<select name = "box1" class="searchbox">
<option value = "">All Values</option>
```

`<?php
global $wpdb;
$ddresult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Field1 FROM pc_table ORDER BY Field1 ASC");
foreach($ddresult as $ddrow) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $ddrow->Field1; ?>"><?php echo $ddrow->Field1; ?> </option>
<?php
} ?>
</select>`

How can I add the code to keep the value selected after form submit? Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It checks if `box1` was submitted. Then it compares that value to the items in the options loop. A match will set `$selected` to the correct attribute, otherwise it will stay an empty string by default. (NB: if form is using get method, then change $POST to $_GET)

```
<select name = "box1" class="searchbox">
<option value = "">All Values</option>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$ddresult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Field1 FROM pc_table ORDER BY Field1 ASC");
foreach($ddresult as $ddrow) {

$selected = '';
if(isset($_POST['box1'])){
  if($ddrow->Field1==$_POST['box1']){ $selected = 'selected="selected"'; }
}
?>
<option value="<?php echo $ddrow->Field1; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $ddrow->Field1; ?> </option>
<?php
} ?>
</select>
```

This example of course does not include if you want to save the submitted value to the database and then re introduce it in the output at a later time. If that's what you would like to know, then please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for replying, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work - the drop down is reverting back to the first item in the list (All Values) once the submit has been pressed.

Comment: It now works perfectly, thank you so much! I am very grateful

Comment: Hey, thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to reply. Have a great day!